# Deep Learning: is there any open-source library that can be integrated with Hadoop streaming and MapReduce?

Tags: python, hadoop

Google search popped out quite a few open source deep learning frameworks. Here is a collected list

```
Google TensorFlow
Theano
mxnet
keras
Pylearn2
Blocks
Lasagne
chainer
scikit-neuralnetwork
theano-lights
deepy
idlf
reinforce.js
opendeep
mxnet.js
CGT
Torch
Caffe
scikit-cuda
cuda4py
```

Which one can be implemented in a straight-forward way with Hadoop streaming and MapReduce?

Python is prefered, other languages can also be considered.

**EDIT:**

Currently I am mainly interested in Deep Reinforcement Learning and LSTM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://deeplearning4j.org/
It does support LSTMs and Deep Reinforcement Learning and Hadoop:
https://deeplearning4j.org/iterativereduce